# Genrating apex class using Tooling API throws exception while using relationship field in SOQL query

Tags: apex, soql, relationships, tooling-api

I am trying to generate apex class using Tooling API.
In the apex class I am writing a query

`[select Type, Origin, Count_of_Co_brand_card__c, CaseUser__r.City, IsEscalated, ClosedDate, SLAViolation__c, CreatedDate from Case where Id IN :recordIds]`

using relationship field **CaseUser__r.City**

On creating the Apex class using Tooling API, I get exception in response as

> "No such column 'City' on entity 'User'. If you are attempting to use
>   a custom field, be sure to append the '__c' after the custom field
>   name. Please reference your WSDL or the describe call for the
>   appropriate
>   names.","errorCode":"INVALID_FIELD_FOR_INSERT_UPDATE","fields":[]

Here, When I create apex class manually consisting same query is saved successfully. Exception I am facing is through Tooling API.
Any ideas?

Comment: The field `City` doesn't exist on the `User` object. Do you mean **MailingCity** (standard) or have you created a custom field called `City` but have forgot to include `__c`.

Comment: @DanJones `City` is a valid field for `User`. I can run the following SOQL query via the API. `Select Id, City from User`

Comment: @DanielBallinger Interesting. You're correct, it must be something else!

Answer (score 1):

According to the [docs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_user.htm), there are some Booleans that determine the `City` field's visibility.

> **UserPreferencesShowCityToExternalUsers**
>
> **Type:** boolean
>
> **Properties:** Create, Filter, Update
>
> **Description:** Indicates the visibility of the city field in the user’s contact information. City is visible only to internal members of the user’s organization when:
>
> - This field is false. When false, this field returns the value #N/A.

Additionally, there is also another Boolean:

> **UserPreferencesShowCityToGuestUsers**
>
> **Type:** boolean
>
> **Properties:** Create, Filter, Update
>
> **Description:** Indicates the visibility of the city field in the user’s contact information. When true, city is visible to guest users. Guest users can access public Site.com and Force.com sites, and public pages in Communities, via the Guest User license associated with each site or community. When false, this field returns the value #N/A.

I'd expect that, potentially, depending on how you're using the API and how you're logged into it, this would throw the error you're seeing in the Tooling API.